# How to increase height of view controller to cover full screen after hiding bottom bar?

Tags: objective-c, hide, fullscreen, uitabbar

I want to achieve 2 things here

1) Hide the bottom bar when I push a view controller

2) Show the full height of the view controller so that it covers the entire height of the 
screen

My code as follows:

```
DMUserProfileViewController *upvc = [[DMUserProfileViewController alloc]initWithNickname:[UserInfo sharedUserInfo].getNickname];
upvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 431);
upvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:upvc animated:YES];
```

However as seen below, the setting of frame does not seem to affect the outcome. (blank space below the viewcontroller). How can I increase the height of the view so that it covers the entire screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove line

```
upvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 431);
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Space is still showing. Just seems like a direct manipulation of the view frame has no effect

Comment: Maybe you changing frame inside DMUserProfileViewController methods? For example, in viewWillAppear. And why you use self.parentController.navigationController? Maybe you can use self.navigationController?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong line of code there. It is supposed to be self.navigationController. Unfortunately that is not the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.tabbar];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but it doesn't work. I believe that it's a size issue and not a z-index issue.

Comment: @Kuf, This looks like a try to answer the question to me than a comment or a clarification.